# System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException - Unrecognized element 'setting'

Tags: c#, configurationmanager

> Unrecognized element 'setting'. (C:\Dev\DOT.NET\AutoPay\ibeam.config line 15)
>
> AppInfo.Sections.Get("AutoPay.Common.Credentials")    'AppInfo.Sections.Get("AutoPay.Common.Credentials")'
>   threw an exception of type
>   'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException'   System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
>   {System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException}

My **config file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
<sectionGroup name="AppInfo" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
  <section name="AutoPay.Common.Credentials" 
           type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
               allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" 
               requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <AppInfo>
    <AutoPay.Common.Credentials>
      <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String"><value>********</value></setting>
      <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String"><value>********</value></setting>
      <setting name="ServiceUrl" serializeAs="String"><value>********</value></setting>
    </AutoPay.Common.Credentials>
  </AppInfo>
</configuration>
```

**Base (abstract) class**:

```
public abstract class BaseConfigInfo : ConfigurationSectionGroup
{
    protected Configuration Configuration;
    protected ConfigurationSectionGroup AppInfo;
    protected ClientSettingsSection Credentials;

    protected BaseConfigInfo(string configFile)
    {
        var fileMap = new ConfigurationFileMap(configFile);
        Configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedMachineConfiguration(fileMap);
        AppInfo = Configuration.GetSectionGroup("AppInfo");

        // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR POPS //
        Credentials = (ClientSettingsSection)AppInfo.Sections.Get("AutoPay.Common.Credentials");
    }

    protected string GetCredentialsString(string kvpName)
    {
        var setting = Credentials.Settings.Get(kvpName);
        return setting.Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
    }

    public string UserName { get { return GetCredentialsString("UserName"); } }
    public string Password { get { return GetCredentialsString("Password"); } }
    public string ServiceUrl { get { return GetCredentialsString("ServiceUrl"); } }
}
```

**Sample concrete class**:

```
public class ConfigInfoIbeam : BaseConfigInfo
{
    public ConfigInfoIbeam() : base(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConfigInfoIbeam"]) { }
}
```

I know I am missing something simple here.  I'm running in .NET 4.  Nothing too usefull showing up when I try to google for this error.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem.  In my config I had this:

```
  <AppInfo>
    <AutoPay.Common.Credentials>
      <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String"><value>********</value></setting>
      <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String"><value>********</value></setting>
      <setting name="ServiceUrl" serializeAs="String"><value>********</value></setting>
    </AutoPay.Common.Credentials>
  </AppInfo>
```

I changed it to:

```
  <AppInfo>
    <AutoPay.Common.Credentials>
      <setting name="UserName" serializeAs="String">
        <value>********</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="Password" serializeAs="String">
        <value>********</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ServiceUrl" serializeAs="String">
        <value>********</value>
      </setting>
    </AutoPay.Common.Credentials>
  </AppInfo>
```

Don't ask me why the underlying xml reader cannot differentiate between the two.  However, problem solved!  grrrr...

Comment: yeah you can also see the explanation here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2010/02/16/system-configuration-configurationerrosexception-unrecognized-element-setting-and-other-unrecognized-elements/ , dont see much sense why this happens..

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `<settings> </settings>` wrapping your three `<setting> .....`.